# KnockoutJS foreach isnt working within remotely loaded modal dialog

Tags: knockout.js

I have a remote modal dialog that once loaded creates a new model with a few bits of info for the modal as such:

```
var modalModel = {
    SessionId: viewModel.SessionId(),
    RetCols: ko.observableArray([])
};

$('#UploadModal').ajaxComplete(function (event, request, settings) {
    ko.applyBindings(modalModel, $('#zupload')[0]);
});
```

This works fine, I'm printing the session id to the modal so I know that info is there and the model is showing in firebug.  However, I have the following function that makes an ajax call and reads the response into the observableArray RetCols.  This APPEARS to be working as I'm printing the length on the page and it shows it has items, but I can not for the life of me foreach it.  Is there something wrong here I am not seeing?   Here is the ajax call:

```
function uploadSubmit() {
$.ajax({
    url: '/Upload/UserSaveFileInfo/',
    type: 'post',
    async: false,
    data: ko.toJSON({
        UploadName: $("#uploadName").val(),
        UploadDescription: $("#uploadDescription").val(),
        Id:  $('#uploadId').val()
    }),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function (result) {
        for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++)
        {
            modalModel.RetCols.push({
                Id: result[i].Id,
                Header: result[i].Header,
                Values: result[i].Values,
                MatchedTo: result[i].MatchedTo,
                ColumnNumber: result[i].ColumnNumber
            });
        }
        alert(modalModel.RetCols().length);  
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
}
```

and here is the bit in my modal that doesnt want to work:

```
<span data-bind="text: modalModel.RetCols().length"></span>  <!-- this works! --> 


<!-- ko foreach: modalModel.RetCols -->
        <div class="control-group" >
            <label class="control-label">
                Column <span data-bind="text: $data.ColumnNumber"></span>
            </label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input data-bind="value: $data.MatchedTo" />
                <span class="help-block" data-bind="text: $data.Values"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

any help would be greatly appreciated!!  Here is a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ZLBpu/154/ it is a little different than what is described above due to the remote loading for the modal but i've more or less duplicated what is happening.

EDIT:  In particular, the ajax call for moveToModal seems to be what is causing this to bomb out.  This fiddle has the same function NOT in an ajax call and it works just as I expected it to:  http://jsfiddle.net/valvemail/RJ8Vx/1/  .  So there has to be something wrong with the ajax call in particular.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to put "$data." before each property inside of the foreach.

**Edit**

I got it to work in jsFiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/sk5BW/)

Using this HTML:

```
<span data-bind="text: RetCols().length"></span>  <!-- this works! --> 

<!-- ko foreach: RetCols -->
    <div class="control-group" >
        <label class="control-label">
            Column <span data-bind="text: $data.ColumnNumber"></span>
        </label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input data-bind="value: $data.MatchedTo" />
            <span class="help-block" data-bind="text: $data.Values"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

And this JS:

```
var modalModel = {
    SessionId: 'a',
    RetCols: ko.observableArray([])
};

modalModel.RetCols.push({
    ColumnNumber: 1,
    MatchedTo: "mt",
    Values: "values"
});

ko.applyBindings(modalModel);
```

**Edit 2**

I took a look at your fiddle. I think the problem is that the viewModel is already bound to the html you are trying to bind the modalModel. To get around this, I restructured the code a bit to make modalModel part of the viewModel. I then put boolean observable on the modalModel that you can toggle to "bind" the modal.

I also put the html you were inserting on the ajax call in the html. I surrounded it with a knockout if binding so that you shouldn't get errors for the properties not existing.

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qfE6Q/1/)

Comment: I've tried it both ways and its still not working... I think that a foreach will work with or without it, I'm just used to dealing with children collections so I've gotten in the habit of using it...

Comment: Ok...I don't think this should be a problem, but have you tried changing "modalModel.RetCols" to "modalModel.RetCols()" on the foreach line?

Comment: I think you misunderstand the question, I apologize if I wasn't clear.   I have 2 seperate view models, one that exists on the parent page, one I am creating when an ajax loaded modal window opens.  modalModel is for the data loaded iframe.  I'd do a fiddle, but since it has a external iframe its been a little tricky... the modalModel is specific to the iframe content only and that is why I apply the model once the ajax has finished loading the iframe content...  ill try to get a fiddle up but i just gotta think of a way to do it in a disconnected fashion.  foreach RetVals() doesnt work either

Comment: Without seeing the fiddle, I am having a little difficulty understanding the entire situation. Hopefully you can get up even a simplified example. In regards to the foreach, I changed "modalModel.RectCols" to just "RectCols". Since you are binding modalModel, you can refer directly to the property. Of course, there may be another problem having to do with the entire page that may prevent this from working, like it does in the fiddle.

Comment: Woo!  that was fun :).  it appears there is something wrong w/ the ajax specifically, because while tinkering to get this fiddle to work, having the function outside of the ajax call did what I expected.  But inside the ajax call it doesn't work or sometimes it may show me a flash of it being there.  Another interesting observation on this was that if I relaunched the modal, the boxes are there.  I hadn't noticed this before because my development version has a series of divs that show/hide as its working... here is the fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/ZLBpu/154/

Comment: Take a look at edit 2, and the new fiddle. Hopefully you'll be able to solve your situation using the format I used.

Comment: The content has to be loaded remotely.  The page I'm bringing over is a view of uploads so it contains an IEnumerable<Uploads> of the users previous uploads.  I'm trying to avoid having to put that on the page unless the user actually elects to open the uploads control...

Comment: You can still load the content remotely. The fiddle I created will not error if the uploads data is empty. I surrounded the area you placed in the js, to be inserted on ajax success, by the ko if binding, so the user will not see it unless you toggle the Bind property to true, which you should only do, once the data loaded successfully.

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't quite work... I really don't think what you described is the problem because it seems that both models are working independently in my fiddle.... i'm printing a line of text from each, if the model was resetting the other bindings from either the model or the modalModel would disappear when the new bindings were applied... in my fiddle -- if you click the move to modal button, it will print the count but not show the boxes.  but if you close the modal, and reopen it, the boxes are there... so the behavior I'm trying to trap is that, how do i force update the modalModel...

Comment: In particular -- check this out -- http://jsfiddle.net/valvemail/RJ8Vx/1/   .  I changed the moveToModal to just execute the for loop directly w/ no ajax wrapper -- it works perfectly!  So there is something in particular within the ajax that is making this thing bomb out...

Comment: Ok...obviously I cannot help you on that part. Glad we got your model working on the client side.